# How to resume training from *.meta in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the latest version of tensorflow, when I save the model I find two files are produced: model_xxx and model_xxx.meta.

Does model_xxx.meta specify the network? Can I resume training using model_xxx and model_xxx.meta without specify the network in the code? What about training queue structure, are they stored in model_xxx.meta?

Comment: See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py#L1348

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but at least for `DNNCLassifiers` you can specify the `model_dir` parameter when creating it and that will construct the model from the files and then you can continue the training.

For the `DNNClassifiers` you specify `model_dir` when first creating the object and the training will store checkpoints and other files on this directory. You can come then after that, and create another `DNNClassifier` specifying the same `model_dir` and that will restore your pre-trained model.